# Can't call functions on ko.protectedObservable in a template

Tags: knockout.js

I have implemented `ko.protectedObservable` as detailed in http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/guard-your-model-accept-or-cancel-edits.html.

My ViewModel is an object with some properties (there are more, but these are the relevant ones):

```
...
self.Title = ko.protectedObservable();
self.Speaker = ko.protectedObservable();
self.Category = ko.protectedObservable();
...
```

On my form, I want to put an undo button next to each field which will restore that field's data back to its original value.  Here is what I came up with:

```
<input type="text" id="Title" data-bind="value: Title" />
<button class="btn" type="button" data-bind="click: Title.reset" title="Undo Changes"><i class="icon-undo"></i></button>
```

This is a lot of repetitive code, so I wanted to move the undo button into a template.  (I can't make a template of the field and the button together because the `Category` and `Speaker` values come from `<select>` tags with varying options and the `Title` is a simple text box, so I want to make a template of the undo button by itself.)  I figured that I would be able to do this:

```
<script type="text/html" id="ajax-editor-undobutton">
    <button class="btn btn-mini" type="button" data-bind="click: reset" title="Undo Changes"><i class="icon-undo"></i></button>
</script>
```

and then use this binding:

```
<!-- ko template: { name: 'ajax-editor-undobutton', data: Title } --><!-- /ko -->
```

However, the click handler does not work.  I stepped through the code in the Chrome Developer Tools and found that when the template is called, the `Title` is evaluated to a string before it is used in the template - and obviously the plain string does not have the `protectedObservable` methods.

Is there a way to bind the `protectedObservable` object to the template so that its reset method can be called from inside the template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple of things you could do.  But the main thing is that you shouldn't make an observable the `data` for any of knockout's bindings, they will be unwrapped.

Since your template only needs the `reset` function, just pass that in as the data instead.

```
<!-- ko template: { 'name': 'ajax-editor-undobutton', 'data': Title.reset } --><!-- /ko -->
<script type="text/html" id="ajax-editor-undobutton">
    <button class="btn btn-mini" type="button" data-bind="click: $data" title="Undo Changes"><i class="icon-undo"></i></button>
</script>
```

Otherwise, you need to wrap the observable into an object so knockout doesn't automatically unwrap the value.

```
<!-- ko template: { 'name': 'ajax-editor-undobutton', 'data': { 'Value': Title } } --><!-- /ko -->
<script type="text/html" id="ajax-editor-undobutton">
    <button class="btn btn-mini" type="button" data-bind="click: Value.reset" title="Undo Changes"><i class="icon-undo"></i></button>
</script>
```

Comment: I am going to use your second answer since I plan to also add a "dirty flag" and use a binding for `css: {disabled: ! Value.isDirty }` on the button.  The second option lets me pass both `reset` and `isDirty` together.